# Power BI desktop reports are not refreshed in Power BI website

Tags: charts, report, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am working with Power BI charts, in one of my current projects I made charts using Power BI Desktop then published those reports into Power BI Service.

Those reports can't be refreshed for 15 minutes, but those reports and charts are refreshed in Power BI Desktop.

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If your data source for report is on-premise, you are required to install and configure power BI gateway. Power BI gateway should be installed on a machine which is always up and running. Gateway is responsible for updating data in power bi cloud from your on-premise data source.

Comment: My data source for report is an Azure SQL Database, I think for azure SQL database there is no need to configure the power bi gateway.

Comment: Yes, for Azure SQL you don't need to configure gateway, it should be refreshed automatically in quite sometime. You are not clear in you question, about the data source. The link you have provided in answer is talking about gateway which is used only for on-premise data sources. Can you please elaborate more to your question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your data source connection settings are correctly configured. In Power BI Desktop, go to "Edit Queries" to check your data source credentials and authentication settings. Make sure they match the settings in the Power BI Service.